# Querying many to many fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In the  models there is a many to many fields as,

from emp.models import Name

```
  def info(request):
     name = models.ManyToManyField(Name)
```

And in emp.models the schema is as

```
 class Name(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=512)


      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
```

Now when i want to query a particular id say for ex:

```
         info=  info.objects.filter(id=a)
         for i in info:
              logging.debug(i.name) //gives an error
```

how should the query be to get the name

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`info.name` is `ManyToManyField` so if you want all `Name` objects associated with it you have to use `.all()` method on it. Only then you'll get list (queryset) of `Name` objects:

```
info_list = info.objects.filter(id=a)
for info_object in info_list:
    for name_object in info_object.name.all():
        print name_object.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Lukasz is right, but just so you know, it doesn't make sense to filter on an id unless you use `info.object.filet(id__in=a)` and a is a list of some sort. If you filter on a single id, you should be using objects.get(**kwargs) first of all, and it will return that specific Info instance instead of a QuerySet.